# FB like button prevents FB login button to appear

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

This async code goes in the header and allows to show a FB like button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.async=true; js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This code goes where the FB like button is shown (together with Google Analytics tracking code)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">_ga.trackFacebook();</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-width="150" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

Everything works good but on a single (a guestbook, actually) page where I have a FB login button ( [Link to the page](http://www.flapane.com/guestbook/guestbook.php) ) positioned at the bottom of the page. The FB login button uses Facebook SDK for PHP.

```
if (!$user): ?>
   <div id="fb-root" style="display:none"></div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> //modifica per validazione w3c
//<![CDATA[
document.write('<fb:login-button size="medium" scope="email">Login with/Accedi con Facebook</fb:login-button>');
//]]>
    </script>
```

It won't appear unless I delete

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

from the FB like button code. The problem is that FB login button needs that fb-root div, too.

It seems that deleting

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

from the FB like button doesn't cause any harm to the button itself. I can still click on LIKE button and add comments. Also, FB login button works again.
Why is that? Is fb-root div useless for FB like buttons? (Actually, quite a few answers on stackoverflow state the opposite)

How do I make the FB login button work good without having to remove fb-root div from FB like button? Any hints?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if things have changed greatly since the question was asked, but I just had the same problem, and solved it by using the FB.init setting: xfbml:true .

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'your-app-id',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true  // if 'false', Login button won't show.
  });
...
};
```

Hope this helps!